# Why is an interface in Java called an "interface"?

Tags: java, terminology, interfaces

I am not sure why an `interface` in Java is called an "interface", but I think it can be one of the following two reasons (or both):

## Reason one:

[This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) says the following:

> Methods form the object's *interface* with the outside world

Based on the above quote, I think that the reason why the `interface` in Java is called an "interface" is because a Java `interface` forces a class that implements that Java `interface` to have a certain interface (by "interface" here I don't mean a **Java `interface`**, what I mean is a **group of methods**, or only one method since a Java `interface` can have one or more methods).

## Reason two:

The word "interface" in the real world means the following (I got this definition from Google):

> a point where two systems, subjects, organizations, etc. meet and
> interact.

So based on the above definition, I can think of a Java `interface` as an entity that sits between two objects, and these two objects communicate with each other through that Java `interface`.

For example, imagine that we have a Java `interface` called `Animal` that have two methods called `move()` and `makeSound()`, and we have a `Cat` class and a `Dog` class and both classes implement the `Animal` interface.

Now we can do something like this:

```
Animal animal1 = new Dog();
animal1.makeSound();
```

We can imagine that `animal1.makeSound()` tells the `Animal` interface to send a `makeSound()` message to the object associated with the `Animal` interface (in this case: a `Dog` object), the following image demonstrate that:

[image]

Now of course the methods of a Java `interface` don't have implementations, but I showed that they do in the above image just to show what happens at a conceptual level, and not to show what actually  happens (even though I guess theoretically we can have a programming language where the methods of an `interface` actually have implementations).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2758619/10585586

Comment: Or this? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/339744/320517

Comment: In programming languages another considered synonym for an interface is _contract_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are interfaces in Java called that way?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339743/why-are-interfaces-in-java-called-that-way)

Answer (score 7):

### A real world analogy

*For the sake of keeping the answer simple, let's say that the only cars that exist are personal vehicles with an automatic gearbox, and let's exclude stick shift and larger vehicles such as buses or trucks.*

If you have a driver's license, then you are able to drive *any* car. Even if you learned to drive in a BMW, you'll also be able to drive a Mercedes or a Fiat. Why is that?

Well, simply put, because all these cars have exactly the same layout. Every car implements this same layout, which is why you can change cars and still know exactly how to operate that new car:

- The steering wheel can be turned lef/right to turn the car left/right
- The right pedal makes the vehicle go forward
- The left pedal makes the vehicle stop going forward
- The gear stick allows you to (dis)connect the engine from the wheels

What I have listed here is a complete list of all interactions between a driver and a car that are required for a driver to correctly drive that car.

This "list of possible interactions" is what we call an **interface**. When you look at both definitions you supplied, you'll see that they fit with my example:

> Methods form the object's interface with the outside world

Translated: "**Pedals/steering weel/gear stick** form the **car**'s interface with the **driver**".

> a point where two systems, subjects, organizations, etc. meet and interact.

The pedals/steering weel/gear stick are the only points where a driver and car interact with one another.

---

### Interfaces in programming

> I can think of a Java interface as an entity that sits between two objects

We need to be very careful with our words here. Some real life examples exist where an interface is an object between two actors, e.g. how a translator facilitates communication between two people who speak different languages.

However, in programming terms, the predominant example is where one actor owns another actor, rather than them being two "cooperating" individuals. In this case, the interface is actually referring to (part of) **the owned actor** itself, rather than a separate layer that sits inbetween them.

Pedantically, your class doesn't need to implement an `interface` to "have an interface". Class methods are an "interface" by themselves, as they describe how a consumer can interact with this class.

However, this scenario invariably ties the class and the "interface" together, i.e. this so-called "interface" only applies to this specific class, and each class has its own "interface".

That's not very useful, since it completely excludes the possibility of multiple classes implementing the same interface, similar to how many cars have the exact same layout for the driver.

So instead of letting the class define its own interface, we create a separate `interface`, which is often called a "contract", i.e. a list of requirements that a class needs to fulfill if it wants to correctly claim that it implements the interface.

When we have that separate interface, we can then have our classes (however many we want) implement that interface.

A simple example:

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Steer(Direction direction);
    void Accelerate();
    void Brake();
}

public class BMW318 : ICar
{
    public void Steer(Direction direction)
    {
        // make the car turn in the requested direction
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        // make the car accelerate
    }

    public void Brake()
    {
        // make the car brake
    }
}

public class Fiat500 : ICar
{
    public void Steer(Direction direction)
    {
        // make the car turn in the requested direction
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        // make the car accelerate
    }

    public void Brake()
    {
        // make the car brake
    }
}
```

To a layman, most cars nowadays seems to be exactly the same, mechanically speaking.If that's how you feel, then the above example doesn't really showcase the power of interfaces.

So I want to take the time here and show you how an interface allows an object to fulfill the same contract but have a completely different implementation:

```
public class Horse : ICar
{
    public void Steer(Direction direction)
    {
        // pull the reins left/right
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        // kick the spurs on the horse
    }

    public void Brake()
    {
        // pull the reins and yell "Woah boy!"
    }
}

public class Donkey : ICar
{
    public void Steer(Direction direction)
    {
        // pull carrot and stick left/right
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        // hold a carrot in front of the donkey
    }

    public void Brake()
    {
        // let the donkey eat the carrot
    }
}
```

This `Horse` and `Donkey` are dramatically different from a `BMW318`, yet they still **can be operated using the same instructions**.

Now that we have these examples, let's showcase the power of an interface in action. The below code works exactly the same for **every** implementation of `ICar`:

```
public void DriveToTheShop(ICar car)
{
    // car is at the house

    car.Accelerate();
    car.Brake();
    car.Steer(Direction.Left);
    car.Accelerate();
    car.Brake();

    // car arrives at the shop
}
```

This is the power of an interface. We're able to define interactions with an object without even knowing what that object is (is it a car? is it a horse? is it a donkey?). The only requirement we have is that all possible objects (`BMW318`, `Fiat500`, `Horse`, `Donkey`) correctly fulfill the `interface` that we defined.

---

### Your interpretation of an interface

When you look at this setup, you could say that there are five "things" in the codebase (`ICar`, `BMW318`, `Fiat500`, `Horse`, `Donkey`). I think you think of an `interface` as a separate layer because it is a separate "thing" in the codebase.

I think that what you're intending to say is correct, but the way you are saying it is ambiguous and leaves your words open for an interpretation where it is not correct.

While it is true that the `interface` is a separate "thing" in the codebase (which we often refer to as an "abstraction layer"), it's often better to think of the interface as being part of a given implementing class (e.g. `Fiat500`), because the class owns its implementation of that interface.

When we're dealing with an object, e.g. a `Fiat500`, then the best way to think of it is that the `Fiat500` **is** an `ICar`, not that there's a separate `ICar` interface.

Comment: *"the interface is actually referring to (part of) the owned actor itself, rather than a separate layer that sits inbetween them"* Can I think of it like this: assume that we have a `Cat` class that have the methods `move()` and `makeSound()` and `jump()`. Now when I do `new Cat()` by itself (i.e. without assigning the returned `Cat` object to a variable), then a `Cat` object will be created, but this `Cat` object will not have an interface (and hence there is no way to access the methods of the `Cat` object)...

Comment: ...however, when I do `Cat cat1 = new Cat()`, what will happen here is that `new Cat()` will create a `Cat` object without an interface, and then when this `Cat` object is assigned to `cat1`, then a `Cat` interface will be added to the `Cat` object (so the `Cat` object now consists of two parts: the `Cat` interface and the `Cat` implementation). Now assume that the `Cat` class implements the `Animal` interface (and the `Animal` interface only have the two methods `move()` and `makeSound()`)...

Comment: ...now if I do `Animal animal1 = cat1`, then what will happen here is that the interface part of the `Cat` object will be replaced with the interface of `Animal`, and so now the two parts that the `Cat` object consists of are the `Animal` interface and the `Cat` implementation, and so now even though the `Cat` object have an implementation for the method `jump()`, I cannot access this method, I can only access the methods `move()` and `makeSound()`...

Comment: ...this is because I can only access the `Cat` object through the `Animal` interface (which is now part of the `Cat` object as I said), and the `Animal` interface only has the methods `move()` and `makeSound()`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Tom. No. You're making it so much more convoluted than it is. When a class implements an interface, any object of that class **by definition** has that interface. It wouldn't make sense to have an object of a class that doesn't have one of that class' method or properties, right? Well, an interface defines properties and methods, so the same logic applies to interfaces. That's really it. When `Cat : IAnimal`, then every `Cat` is an `IAnimal`. There's no way of escaping the interface that your class definition defines, when using that class as an object's type.

Comment: @Tom: A better way to think of it is a monster that can only eat `IMeat`, as that's the only thing it can digest. Many things are meat (`Sausage : IMeat`, `PorkChop : IMeat`, `Cat : IMeat`). If you put this monster in a room with sausages, pork chops and cats, all it's going to see it objects of meat. This is because the monster only sees these objects as the `IMeat` that they are. The monster doesn't distinguish any further, because it doesn't need to. Food is food. The food just has to be `IMeat`. The monster can _indiscriminately_ chew up any object that is `IMeat`.

Comment: @Tom: If you further consider that `Broccoli` does _not_ implement `IMeat`, you can therefore see why the monster will refuse to eat it. The compiler effectively prevents you from trying to feed non-meats to this monster. This particular monster can eat any `IMeat`, but there's another monster who eats only `Cat`, so the compiler refuses to let you feed it sausage/pork chop/broccoli, these all cause a compiler error. And there's another monster who eats any `object`, so the compiler lets you feed it anything you want (sausages, pork chops, cats, broccoli, ...)

Comment: @Tom: As a last consideration, you need to realize that others can interpret this same `Cat` object differently. While our original monster just treats it like a piece of `IMeat`, someone else can treat this same object as the `Cat` that it is. If `Cat` defines a `Pet()` method that is _not_ defined in the `IMeat` interface, then I am able to pet this object because I know it's a `Cat`, but this monster cannot pet the object that he sees as being `IMeat` and nothing else. Interfaces are a _subset_ of the public methods and properties of an object. All others the object has are obscured.

Comment: I think I understand it now. So in my example in my previous comments, the `Cat` interface in the `Cat` object is an integral part of the `Cat` object that cannot be removed, it will always be part of the `Cat` object, however, this doesn't mean that I can only treat the `Cat` object as a `Cat`, yes, I can treat the `Cat` object as a `Cat` (by assigning it to a variable of type `Cat`) which would allow me to access the entire interface of `Cat` (so I would be able to send the `Cat` object the messages `move()` and `makeSound()` and `jump()`)...

Comment: ...but also, I can treat the `Cat` object as an `Animal` (by assigning it to a variable of type `Animal`) which would allow me to only access the `Animal` interface part of the `Cat` interface (so I would only be able to send the `Cat` object the messages `move()` and `makeSound()`). Am I correct?

Comment: @Tom: I think you're spot on now. Essentially, objects are what they are, but others can treat them as a "lesser" type (i.e. an implemented interface or a base class). For more information, look up polymorphism, which is specifically what we're talking about here. The principle of polymorphism is the same for inheritance and interface implementation.

Comment: "Pedals/steering weel/gear stick form the car's interface with the driver"." - is that a proper English sentence?  Would anybody actually _say_ that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: It is, by semantical English _and_ developer jargon, an interface between the driver and the car. Whether that specific sentence is commonly uttered is irrelevant. Also, if you're that distracted by the English grammar, just substitute "Pedals/steering weel/gear stick" with "These things".

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the word [interface](https://www.etymonline.com/word/interface) is quite old since it would date from 1874. Its latin roots mean:

- inter: between (like in inter-action or inter-national)
- facies: the form, the appearance (like in sur-face, or face-to-face when considering human appearance).

Computer science has revived this rather geometrical (or chemical?) term related to “*a surface that forms the boundaries between two bodies*”, by adapting it to the boundaries between  hardware (who remembers the shape of an RS232C interface?) or software components.

In component-oriented software in general, and in OOP in particular, the boundaries are defined in terms of what is visible to the outer world for interacting with the component, as opposed to what’s purely  internal to the component. The term “interface” was hence naturally adopted by the community.

When [James Gosling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling) designed Java, based on C++ roots, he inntended to keep it simple and less error-prone:

- In C++, defining an interface requires you to define a class. If you want an abstract interface without any implementation, you need an abstract class with only pure virtual members (if you expect run-time polymorphism). So you quickly end-up with some kind of multiple inheritance, which is difficult to master and very error-prone.
- On the other side, having object conforming to an interface for the benefit of [code reuse, or object composition](https://www.artima.com/intv/gosling3.html), is something semantically different from class inheritance. Decoupling  a class from the interfaces it exposes, has hence the benefit of increased simplicity and more precise expressivity.

This lead Gosling to create a new language construct, and the term *interface* was then quite natural and obvious.

***Edit:** As Jörg W Mittag points out in the comments, it appears that the feature was not completely new but borrowed from Objective-C's protocols.  This doesn't change the explications about the origin of the naming: the interface is the more widely used concept in OOP community.  You can for example see in this [this 1988 article](https://www.drdobbs.com/object-oriented-programming-and-database/184407916) of the popular DDJ magazine that "interface" was even used to make the term "protocol" in an experimental OOP language more understandable.*

Comment: Especially in C++, non-members can be an integral part of an interface, which actually need not have any class. An `interface` is restricted to members though.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you for this very interesting and relevant remark.

Comment: @Christophe: "When James Gosling designed Java, based on C++ roots" – [Java is based on Objective-C, not C++](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html). The feature called `interface` in Java is taken *directly* from Objective-C *protocols*, which in turn are taken from Smalltalk protocols, which are of course based on the idea of protocols in networking, given the messaging metaphor of OO. Quote: "I'm pretty sure that Java's
'interface' is a direct rip-off of Obj-C's 'protocol' which was largely
designed by these ex-NeXT'ers..." and "it has no similarity to C++ as a language."

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for this interesting information. Indeed, in his [whitepaper on Java](https://www.stroustrup.com/1995_Java_whitepaper.pdf) Gosling explains how the language has its root in C++ but that the concept of interface is directly inspired from Objective-C's *protocols* (page 54). No need for guessing:  Gosling co-wrote that paper. Funnily, it took me half an hour to find back where I could have found the whitepaper, browsing through dozen of interview, just to find it back on the website of Stroustrup ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag (the fact that interfaces were meant to avoid multiple inheritance as I also claim is documented, page 28) - I made an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Another word for interface is protocol: *The way by which two or more things are to interact.*

In essence both of your definitions are correct, and indeed have been implemented in that way across different languages/runtimes.

1. Every method, property, field, etc.. defined within a class definition is part of the interface that the object provides/Type that the object is. Some of that interface is available to other parts of the software, some of it is purely for the runtime so that it can accurately emulate an Object instance.
2. Each interface implementation describes a subset of behaviour that should be provided to those who do not wish to deal with an object's totality, merely its compliance to a given protocol.

But these are probably not why `interface` is the used keyword. From what I can find on the issue it appears Java borrowed this from Objective-C, although there are numerous older languages that use either the keyword `interface` or describe a similar keyword as an interface, such as abstract objects in C++ that have no implementation/data members.

Comment: Generally, non-members can also be part of the interface, though not the `interface`.

Comment: It *is* a direct clone of Objective-C *protocol*. As to why they renamed it, I guess they felt the messaging metaphor for OO would be too confusing to C++ programmers, one of the major target audiences of Java.

Answer (score 0):

An *interface* is the part of a system you interact with.

It should be well-designed (easy to use right, hard to misuse or abuse, reasonably easy to implement and test), and well-specified (fully documented, separately from any potential implementation). The importance of having/making good implementations for inspiration and evaluation of the design should also not be underestimated.

Every `class` consists of an *interface*, and its (hidden?) implementation.

As an `interface` in Java only consists of the *interface* part of a `class` *, and not also the implementation, that's probably why they chose the name.
Also, it's catchy, and marketing is king.

<sub>* Default implementations weakened that though.</sub>

Comment: *"Every class consists of an interface, and its (hidden?) implementation"* Does that mean that when we do something like this: `Car car1 = new Car();`, then the variable `car1` is considered to be an interface, and the `Car` object created using `new Car()` is the object that is associated with the `car1` interface? and the only way to access this `Car` object is through its interface (which is `car1`)? and so the variable `car1` and the `Car` object can be considered to be two separate entities (`car1` is an interface entity, and the `Car` object is an object entity)?

Comment: `car1` is a variable, specifically a reference to an object of type `Car`. And `Car` has an *interface* consisting of all its defined members, which are member- and static- functions and variables, constructors, destructor, and member-types, parent-class and implemented `interface`s, as well as their defined behavior. Due to restrictions of Java there are no non-class entities. The one really unfortunate thing about naming `interface`s that way is the confusion about what an *interface* is resulting from that choice.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The confusion is especially prevalent with the "Program to an Interface not to an Implementation" maxim from the GoF book. *Everybody* assumes it is talking about `interface`s when in fact, *none of the languages* used in the book even has such a feature. I have seen teachers grade well-abstracted, well-factored code badly because it "wasn't programming to an interface" and giving As to other code that simply had an `IFoo` for every `Foo` class that was nothing but an exact copy with all method bodies removed for "programming to an interface".

Comment: @JörgWMittag It was a fight getting even a hint of that in the [tag-wiki](/tags/interfaces/info) here, I gave up on the excerpt. So many rejected edits...